# If X = between 0 and 128 and Y = 0 and approaching 64 how to I figure out the Min/Max Theta so that Y = 64 before X < 0 or > 128

Tags: math, trigonometry

I'm working on a missile command like game for an arduboy.

The Bombs fall from the top of the screen Y = 0 and hit the "ground" at Y = 63. The bombs come in at angles, so I can calculate it with a bit of trig:

BombX = initialBombX - bombDistanceTraveled * cos(bombTheta)

BombY = 0 - bombDistanceTraveled * sin(bombTheta)

This works great, but I want to randomize the Theta. However, I want the bomb to always hit the "ground" (y = 63) before it goes off screen (x < 0 or x > 128).

See this drawing for a visual (White lines = good, Red Lines = bad)

[image: red lines bad theta, white lines good theta]

Could someone help me come up with an equation to limit the theta with the constraints:

Initial X will be between 0 and 128

Initial Y will always be 0

if Y <= 63 Then X > 0 && X < 128

Thank You!

Comment: @Spinkoo ok I will delete this question and go back to math class, farewell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math, not programming.

Comment: Don't have such a narrow view, mathematics, logic and programming are closely related.

Comment: This is easier to do (both for you and for computations in-game) if you change how you look at the problem. Your real constraints are that all bombs end between 0 < endX < 128. It sounds like you want to always start from the top (i.e. not from also the top portion of the edges), so you know 0 < startX < 128. Thus, just pick your startX and endX. You don't need to worry about picking a theta that will result in the bomb being off screen. In fact, you never need to know theta. You never need to use trig. You can calculate the slope of the line (once) and just quickly compute the X for any Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple trigonometry:

```
tan(theta) = x/y
```

so theta must be between

```
-arctan(x/63)
```

and

```
arctan((128-x)/63)
```

for an arbitrarily chosen x between 0 and 128, assuming that straight downward is theta=0

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i needed, It's been 20 years since I've touched trig, i forgot about inverted geometry functions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can simplify things a bit. Sine and cosine calculation may appear slow, so we can initially randomize x start coordinate, as well as x approaching coordinate. Then:

```
xDelta = approachX - initialX;
bombX = initialX + ((( bombY + 1 ) * xDelta ) >> 6);
```